# Jquery window resize keeps increasing height of div

Tags: jquery

I'm currently developing a website with a div that needs to be increased and descreased with the background-image.

The js that I have now works fine, except when resizing the window it keeps on increasing the height pixels.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.content-repeat').each(function(){
            var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();  
            $(this).innerHeight(function(i,x){
            return x + parentHeight -284+'px';
            });
            $(this).css('margin-top',-parentHeight +170+'px');
            $(this).css('margin-bottom',-170+'px');
        })
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('.content-repeat').each(function(){
            var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();  
            $(this).innerHeight(function(i,x){
            return x + parentHeight -284+'px';
            });
            $(this).css('margin-top',-parentHeight +170+'px');
            $(this).css('margin-bottom',-170+'px');
        })  
        })
    });
```

Do you have a suggestion for how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you intend to pass a function to innerHeight()? Perhaps you simply mean to pass `x + parentHeight -284+'px'` directly to it?

Comment: The code is exactly doing what I what expect on resizing. And I'm not really a good js developer :(. So maybe the code is not as pretty.

Comment: The code I'm asking about is your resizing code, although now I see that you're doing the same thing in both places. This code is not working the way you think it is.

Comment: any way to fix it? I use it to make a div the exact same height as the parent. I use this for a transparent background image that has to repeat.

Comment: Pass a value into it, not a function. See my first comment.

Comment: Like this? $(this).innerHeight(function(x + parentHeight -284+'px')); That's not working :(

Comment: Actually, you want to use height, not innerHeight. Call it like this: `$(this).height(x + parentHeight -284+'px')`

Comment: The height is not increasing or decreasing when I resize the window.

Comment: Try setting up a fiddle that shows the problem.